# プラグイン更新後？にビルドエラーになる

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

プラグイン更新後？にビルドがうまく行かなくなってしまいました。
ソースはKotlinスタートブックに載っているコードと同じです。(250頁までの内容)
REPLで色々試してみたかったので、下記ファイルを作成しました。

```
kotlin:sample.kt
package com.se.testuser.qiitacliant

class sample {
    // nullを返すかもしれないメソッド
    fun returnNullableStr(arg: String): String? {
        if (arg == "null") return null
        return "not null"
    }

    // nullを返さないメソッド
    fun returnNotNullStr(arg: String): String {
        return "not null"
    }
}
```

下記のように表示されましたので、
restart部分をクリックして再度ビルドしました。
    You’re running the REPL with outdated classes: Build module 'app' and restart

すると下記のようなエラーが出ました。

```
エラー:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'QiitaCliant'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         project :
```

ビルド>プロジェクトの再ビルドを実行すると正常に終了します。

```
情報:Gradle タスク [clean, :app:assembleDebug]
C:\Users\testuser\AndroidStudioProjects\QiitaCliant\app\src\main\kotlin\com\se\testuser\qiitacliant\sample.kt
警告:(15, 26) Parameter 'arg' is never used
情報:BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 41s
情報:0 個のエラー
情報:1 個の警告
情報:コンソールの完全な出力を参照してください
```

エラーメッセージから下記2つが見つからないのはわかるのですが、どこに設定追加すればいのでしょうか？
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar

build.gradleの中身も記載しておきます。

build.gradle(プロジェクトルートの方)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(appルートの方)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    // 設定追加ここから
    sourceSets {

        // ここはテスト用。
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    // 設定追加ここまで

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.se.testuser.qiitacliant"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

下記のとおり実施することでエラーを修正できました。

- SDKを25 -> 26に変更(build.gradle(appルートの方)を変更)